# The system cannot find the path specified, but then displays result

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, cmd, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to learn about gherkin, cucumber, npm in vscode.

I'm getting the usual "The system cannot find the path specified" error message, but then the result is shown as normal underneath.

```
C:\projects\vscode1>npm --version
The system cannot find the path specified.
7.11.2
```

It also does not recognize paths with "." in them, so "C:\projects\vscode1>./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js" shows a different error.

```
C:\projects\vscode1>./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The folder definitely exists inside node_modules as .bin.

During npm installation the cmd for the extra components, where it installs chocolatey etc, would not complete so I'm not sure if this is related. I have done a repair on the installer but it did not fix the problem.

**UPDATED**

I can run it in CMD without this .bin problem, but there is no output. The code I'm trying to run is:

```
const { Given } = require("@cucumber/cucumber")

//const (Given) = require('cucumber')

Given('a user opens {string}', (url) => {
    console.log(url)
})
```

vscode.feature

```
Feature: vscode feature

    Feature Description

        Scenario: Scenario name
        Given a user opens "https://www.duckduckgo.com/"
```

The tutorial can be found at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsGr6xjZ0mY

Comment: Try `.\node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js`

Comment: It worked, thanks JosefZ. Is this due to windows vs Linux command lines? BTW I still have the issue of "The system cannot find the path specified."